# Prevent chef-client from logging messages twice

Tags: chef-infra

Whenever I run `chef-client`, as it's executing my recipes I get the messages logged to the console twice.

For example:

```
[2017-06-01T15:05:22-05:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because override_runlist was given
[2017-06-01T15:05:22-05:00] WARN: Skipping final node save because override_runlist was given
[2017-06-01T15:05:22-05:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 1.187499 seconds
[2017-06-01T15:05:22-05:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 1.187499 seconds
[2017-06-01T15:05:22-05:00] INFO: Skipping removal of unused files from the cache
[2017-06-01T15:05:22-05:00] INFO: Skipping removal of unused files from the cache
```

Is there a reason why this happens, and if so is it possible to have it log only one of the messages?

```
c:\chef>chef-client --version
Chef: 13.0.118
```

**Edit:** If I inspect `chef-client.log` I see that it (correctly) only logs a message once. It is only to the console that I see the doubling up of messages

Comment: Got both a downvote and a close vote.  I'm assuming someone wants more detail in my question?  I would be happy to provide any extra information if I knew what would be useful.

Comment: Does it happen with all output from the start of the run?

Comment: I think it is common with Chef 13. Console logs are doubled. I think I have raised this issue on chef's Slack and I was told it's a bug/feature. It is easy to reproduce, start test kitchen with log_level info - it is always logging double for me.

Comment: @ThaDon Yeah, that's pretty strange. Try to set -L /path/to/the/log/file, then you won't have the same line twice ...